# Formatting toolbar in document editing app

Tags: formatting, toolbar, editor, document

I'm working on a web app (not mobile) which allows the creation and collaboration of legal documents.  The business owner wants to have a fixed toolbar, as per this editing tool I'm using to write this question, or as per Microsoft Word, etc.

I personally like the way Medium works, in that you have to highlight the text you want to edit and then it brings up mini toolbar, just above the text.

What do you think works best from a UX perspective?

Comment: Can you show your current work?

Comment: I personally hate the mini toolbar popups, so much that I go to the pain of disabling these where possible. What did you learn from testing with future users and/or asking the business owner for their reasons?

Comment: It's so early on that we're only just working on wireframes.  I will be testing everything when we get to a front end prototype.

Comment: The business owner thinks that her customers would want to use an existing understood paradigm.  The issue is that there is going to be a lot on the page and I'm trying to keep the default view as simple as clean as possible...

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of an opinion based question, but I will attempt to answer it nevertheless...

It is probably best to stick to that which the end users are already used to.

Remember that this is UX (user experience), and as such, the user's previous [user] experience counts greatly, as you don't really want to change their expectations *too much*.

I am not at all familiar with legal documents, or their editing, but assuming that they are created on standard word processing tools, then it would seem best to stick to what they already know, use and love.

If, however, *Medium* is common in their line of work and a greater proportion of your users use that, and are familiar with the need to select a portion of text in order see the menu and to be able to edit it, then fine. However, to me, it sounds like a GUI version of a line editor, to be honest.  Having to select something and then have a movable menu, does not sound particularly consistent, although, I can see that having the menu nearer the text, would result in less mouse movement.

Basically you have a conflict between:

- less mouse movement (for the pop up menu), and;
- familiarity and automatic (subconscious) hand movement (for the static "normal" menu).

You say that you are primarily concerned with having a clean display, so how about a compromise, à la WordPress, where there are a number of familiar tools immediately on display, and then there is a **More...** menu? Or have a very simplistic toolbar, for the common actions, like TextEdit on the Mac, or the StackExchange editing tool, and then have the more advanced features, either in menus or in optional toolbars. Letting the user decide how they want their toolbars to appear, if at all, is generally the best approach (within reason).

You probably don't have the market clout (or do you?) to change the UI drastically, in the same way that MS did when they introduced Office 2007 and the [Fluent User Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office#Windows_versions), and user's productivity, arguably, dipped for a while, until the user's got used to the new design, or switched to using something more familiar, like OpenOffice, which still had the old style menus and toolbar. So, in order to encourage people to adopt your UI/UX and hence your application, it is best to draw them in with something familiar. Thereafter, once you have built up a firm and loyal user base, *then* you could bring in the new UI (maybe).